# passing props from functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have three files

**video_list.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import VideoListItem from'./video_list_item';
const VideoList=(props)=>{
    const videoItems=props.vid.map(function(single){ 
            return <VideoListItem vidobject={single}/>
    })
        return (
            <ul className="col-md-4 list-group">
            {videoItems}
            </ul>
            );
    };

export default VideoList;
```

**video_list_item.js**

```
 import React from 'react';
 const VideoListItem=(props)=>{
    return <li>hello there</li>
 }

 export default VideoListItem;
```

**index.js**

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import YTSearch from 'youtube-api-search';
import SearchBar from './components/search_bar';
import VideoList from './components/video_list';
const API_KEY="AIzaSyCJc1jURCORLEuk";

class App extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state={videos:[]};
        YTSearch({key:API_KEY,term:'javascript'},(videosfetched)=>{
            this.setState({videos:videosfetched});
            });
    }
    render(){
    return (<div>
                <SearchBar></SearchBar>
                <VideoList vid={this.state.videos} />
            </div>
    ) ;
   }    
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.querySelector('.container'));
```

I have been watching react tutorial which makes YouTube clone and i have confusion with some piece of code.the code is from the videos.
1.In the **video_list.js** file i am passing a prop from a functional component **VideoList** to other functional component **VideoListItem**,is it valid?
 
I thought that only class based component can pass props to child components.
2.what does the **map()** return ,bcz **videoItems** is storing what **map()** is returning,and i think that it is returning nothing because in return we are just passing props to child component **VideoListItem**
3.when i run it on my server then output is

- hello there
- hello there
- hello there
- hello there
- hello there

i don't understand how this output is coming

Comment: I think that you should check the basic principles of passing props to a child. There is nothing special in this case and the behavior is the one expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.In the video_list.js file i am passing a prop from a functional component VideoList to other functional component VideoListItem,is it valid?

Yes, it's perfectly valid. VideoListItem will receive a prop, accessible with

```
props.vidobject
```

which will be a single item in VideoList's array of videos.

2.what does the map() return ,bcz videoItems is storing what map() is returning,and i think that it is returning nothing because in return we are just passing props to child component VideoListItem

map() takes a function as its input argument, which defines a transformation for each item in the array, from the existing type of the item to the output type of the function.

So each item in props.vid will be transformed from a video into the output of the mapping function:

```
<VideoListItem vidobject={single}/>
```

i.e. it will create an array of VideoListItem React components, where each index receives as a prop the video object in the array, props.vid.

3.when i run it on my server then output is

hello there

hello there

hello there

hello there

hello there

This isn't surprising. You're taking an array of videos, and currently just saying "turn each video into the following React component":

```
<li>hello there</li>
```

You can see this more clearly by using a property on each video within the VideoListItem - for example, if each video has an ID,

```
<li>hello {props.vidobject.id}</li>
```

EDIT** response to comment:

You're correct in saying "the 'VIdeoListItem' is the single component defined in the video_list_item.js".

What that means is that VideoListItem is *defined* in one place, but that React component is reusable - which is part of the point of React. Take the following code:

```
const VideoListItem = function(props) {
  return <div>Hello world</div>
}

<div id="example">
  <VideoListItem />
  <VideoListItem />
<div>
```

What I've done here is *define* the component in one place, but I can then use JSX to put that component in multiple places. Imagine it as...

```
div(
  VideoListItem(),
  VideoListItem(),
)
```

You're 'invoking' the VideoListItem function multiple times, meaning you'll get the same output multiple times. Hence, the above would give the output

Hello world
Hello world

You're seeing multiple lines of output because the code you've written says "give me a <\VideoListItem> (which will print "hello world") once for each item in the array, videoItems", so clearly videoItems contains multiple elements. You can confirm this by writing the below in the render() function of App:

console.log(this.state.videos.length);

Comment: now i understand what is happening map() will make const 'videoItems' as [<VideoListItem vidobject={single}/>,<VideoListItem vidobject={single}/>,<VideoListItem vidobject={single}/>,<VideoListItem vidobject={single}/>,<VideoListItem vidobject={single}/>].....these all values inside array are react components .....and when we write {videoItems} then each of the array elements calls the child component ....and then child component returns "hello world"....hope i am correct!?

Comment: ...const VideoList=(props)=>{
    const videoItems=props.vid.map(function(single){ 
            return <VideoListItem vidobject={single}/> ...so the return code is actually does not send any props to child component ,it is just modifying value of "const videoItems".....correct?

Comment: Not quite. It's worth keeping track of which props in one component are the props of the parent component. So... VideoList receives an array, which it knows as "props.vid". This prop is provided by App, which knows them as this.state.videos. videos is probably just an array of data, not React components. But in App, we say "render a VideoList component, giving it my videos as its 'vid' prop." In VideoList, we render a VideoListItem FOR EACH video in props.vid. VideoListItem only knows that video as "props.vidobject". Is that clear?

Comment: The function, fn, passed to props.vid.map(fn) says "given an item, i, from the array, render a VideoListItem. Pass i to that VideoListItem component as a prop called "vidobject".

Comment: "given an item, i, from the array, render a VideoListItem. Pass i to that VideoListItem component as a prop called "vidobject".....u said render a VideoListItem ,but i dont anything on the server as output until i write {videoItems}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183375/discussion-between-nitishy2j-and-seraph).

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing in `video_list.js` is returning an array or a list of presumably video objects that you just fetched from that YouTube API and for each video object, you are going to render a single video item inside of `video_list_item.js`.

This is why you are mapping over the array of videos inside of `video_list.js` with `map()` and for each individual video object you are going to `return` or render an individual video via the `video_list_item` component.

I would recommend learning more about the `map()` helper because it is widely used and you will get a ton of use out of it just as you are doing in this project.

It looks like your `App` component is what is showing the video list and then the `video_list` component in turn is going to render out all of the different video items via `video_list_item` component.

You created a functional component inside of `video_list.js` because your goal with that component is simply to render some jsx on the screen and its the same with your `video_list_item` component.

Class-based components are not the only ones that can pass `props`, you may be confusing `props` with `state`.

Ask yourself, what is the goal of a component?

The goal of a component is to show content to the user or react to user interaction. Well, the purpose of `props` is to customize those two things inside of a component and so yes, it is valid to pass `props` from one functional component to another one.

A parent component does not have to be a class-based component to pass `props`, if that is what you are thinking.

A class-based component, is for complex logic, something that needs to respond to user input, you need to make network requests then you are going to want to make a class-based component instead of functional one.